# h-sorting in Shell sort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, shellsort

In shell sort, `3h+1` sequence is recommended to h-sort a list using insertion sort

`//1, 4, 13, 40, ...`

Optimal formula to compute start value of `h` is one-third of `listsize`, as shown below,

```
int h = 1;
while(h < listSize/3){ // why N/3?

  h = 3*h + 1
}
while(h >= 1){

  //h-sort the array
  // perform insertionSort
  h = h/3;
}
```

Question:

To perform shell sort, How to prove mathematically that `h`(at max) should be less than `listSize/3`?

Comment: Any decreasing sequence of `h` values ending at 1 is guaranteed to produce a sorted list. So `h` (at max) can be any value. In fact, quite a few different sequences of `h` values have been proposed. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) for details.

Comment: @user3386109 So, `h < listSize/3` is just a random limit for sorting, in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we continue to increase `h` after condition `(h < listSize/3)`, `h` becomes larger than `listSize`, and there is no sense in h-sorting - we cannot  compare items `A[i]` and `A[i+h]` because the second index is beyond list range.

Answer (score 3):

The optimal sequence that is recommended for Shell sort is called a [Knuth Sequence](https://oeis.org/A003462) and what it actually is `3h+1` with h starting from 0 and is replaced by the solution of the previous equation.

```
h=0;    3*0+1=1
h=1;    3*1+1=4
h=4;    3*4+1=13
h=13;   3*13+1=40 and so on.
```

now for Shell sort, it is recommended that you follow this sequence in the **reverse** **order** when choosing the optimal "gap". To do that, you have to find the last "gap" which is lesser than the `listsize`.

Imagine your list is of size n=100, then you want gaps to be 40,13,4,1

```
int gap;
for(int h=0; h<n; h=h*3+1)
    gap=h;
```

this will get you to 40. Now you do your **Insertion Sort** and you get to the previous gap value as `gap=gap/3` technically `gap=(gap-1)/3` but since the remainder is discarded, we don't worry about it.

So you get the final code of something like:

```
for(int h=0; h<n; h=h*3+1)
    gap=h;

while(gap>=1)
{
    //insertion sort with gap increments
    gap=gap/3;
}
```